# What is meant by "a codon codes for an amino acid"?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology

What is meant by "a codon codes for an amino acid"? Does it mean in order to build that amino acid you must combine those three nucleotides?

Does it mean anything more than provides the instructions for manufacturing that amino acid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does not means "provides instructions for manufacturing an amino acid".  How could three little letters encode so much?

A codon is a three nucleotide sequence that matches the anti-codon of a t-RNA molecule capable of carrying one kind of amino acid.  The GGG codon, for instance, binds the t-RNA that binds to glyceine.  So the codon GGG in an mRNA ends up amounting to "put a glyceine here in the amino acid chain"

Comment: I'm not sure this kind of question should be answered. I know it's easy to toss off a quick answer to help the OP, but should this not be closed instead of posting an answer? Maybe a comment if you want to help? I would liken it to asking for a dictionary definition on EL&U... OT due to lack of research.